# How can I increment a counter in steps of 50?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have the following code

```
package lts

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class BankingSimulation extends BaseSimulation {
  val paginateThroughCustomTransactionsView = scenario("Scenario 04: Paginate through custom transactions view")
    .feed(csv("scenario04.csv").circular)
    .exec(http("04_paginateThroughCustomTransactionsView")
      .get("/api/savings/transactions?viewfilter=${viewEncodedkey}&offset=0&limit=50")
      .header("accept", "application/json")
      .check(jsonPath("$..encodedKey").saveAs("myEncodedKey"))
    )
    .asLongAs("${myEncodedKey.exists()}","offsetCounter", exitASAP = false) {
      exec(http("04_paginateThroughCustomTransactionsView")
        .get("/api/savings/transactions?viewfilter=${viewEncodedkey}&offset=${offsetCounter}&limit=50")
        .header("accept", "application/json")
        .check(jsonPath("$..encodedKey").saveAs("myEncodedKey"))
      )
    }


  setUp(
 paginateThroughCustomTransactionsView.inject(incrementConcurrentUsers(1).times(1).eachLevelLasting(1))
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Right now the scenario works but the offsetCounter is incremented by 1 everytime. How can I increment it by 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps a nicer way... don't rely on the loop counter and use a feeder instead

```
var offsetFeeder = (50 to 1000 by 50).toStream.map(i => Map("offsetCounter" -> i)).toIterator
```

then inside your .asLongAs block, just

```
.feed(offsetFeeder)
```

and execute your "04_paginateThroughCustomTransactionsView" call

Comment: That is also great, but unfortunately I need the test to run based on time not a limit. But this will definitely help me somewhere else :D Thanks!

Comment: aren't you just looping until you don't have a result for myEncodedKey?

Comment: Well, kinda... It's more of a sanity check that the data is there. ~1mil encoded keys to paginate through. It takes several hours to go through all, but I am interested more in setting up 30m tests for each new app version.

Comment: if you want to loop for a finite amount of time, you can do that with a scala finiteDuration. eg: `.exec(session => session.set("timeout", 3 hours.fromNow))
        .asLongAs(session("timeout").as[Deadline].hasTimeLeft) {...}`

Comment: I haven't moved to gatling 3 yet, but I see it now has some native support for this sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently you can do all sorts of operations with the session. Before running the call (the `exec`) in the `.asLongAs` part, you have to

```
exec {session =>
 val offsetCounter = session("counter").as[Int] * 50
 session.set("offsetCounter", offsetCounter)
}
```

so the code becomes

```
val paginateThroughCustomTransactionsView = scenario("Scenario 04: Paginate through custom transactions view")
    .feed(csv("scenario04.csv").circular)
    .exec(http("04_paginateThroughCustomTransactionsView")
      .get("/api/savings/transactions?viewfilter=${viewEncodedkey}&offset=0&limit=50")
      .header("accept", "application/json")
      .check(jsonPath("$..encodedKey").saveAs("myEncodedKey"))
    )
    .asLongAs("${myEncodedKey.exists()}","counter", exitASAP = false) {
      exec {session =>
        val offsetCounter = session("counter").as[Int] * 50
        session.set("offsetCounter", offsetCounter)
      }
      .exec(http("04_paginateThroughCustomTransactionsView")
        .get("/api/savings/transactions?viewfilter=${viewEncodedkey}&offset=${offsetCounter}&limit=50")
        .header("accept", "application/json")
        .check(jsonPath("$..encodedKey").saveAs("myEncodedKey"))
      )
    }
```